# How to use expression to change cfgridcolumn textColor

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to change the color of a cfgrid according to the data. This code works perfectly:

```
<cfgridcolumn name="Delta" width="45" 
     select="no" 
     header="Delta" 
     bold="yes" 
     textColor = "(CX LT 0 ? red : blue)">
```

But the color `green` won't work. It just turns to black. I also tried using a hex color instead of web colors and that didn't work either. The only 2 color choices that worked where red and blue. According to [this site](https://www.hks.harvard.edu/research/Macromedia/HomeSite+/Help/CFML_Reference/cfgridcolumn.htm), `green` should work.

Grid Type is Applet

Comment: Try `#(CX LT 0 ? red : blue)#` or maybe `#IIF(CX < 0, "red", "blue")#`

Comment: (Edit) That link is very old (CF4 looks like)!  Truthfully I am a little skeptical about this code working ;-) Can you please post a *small* repro case that demonstrates the issue you described?

Comment: Green is not in the list. you can use hex code with ##. check this link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7adc.html

Comment: (Edit) @techLove - Depends on what type of grid they are using (which they did not say unfortunately). That list is for applets (shudder). If it is an HTML grid, the docs say the value must be "a valid HTML color". Thomas - BTW, that is why I asked about a small [repro case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting a self contained example makes it a lot easier for folks to assist, and the easier it is for someone to test the code .. the faster you will get an answer.

Comment: @Leigh sorry left out that small important detail. It type of Applets. I both Flash and HTML type where giving me other troubles. Also I will post a repro case when I get back to a computer. Thank you Leigh!